# compatibility Android 3.* with android 4

Tags: android, api, tablet

I want to build Android application. My target devices is tablets (not smartphones). Today exist only 3.* version of android OS, aimed for tablets. Is it normal if i begin build application for tablets in 3.* API? The tablets which will be release with android 4.0 (ice cream sandwich) can to run my application built on 3.0 API? Or me better to wait for 4.0 API if my target devices is tablets? 
Generally, in which version of API to develop my app for tablets? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the applications which run on `Android 3.*` will run on `Android 4.*` too, because there is no point of making and OS if the old application will not run and all the developers have to build their applications for the next version. So I suggest to build your application for `Android 3.*` if your target devices are tablets.

Comment: thank you for answer. How you think - better to develop on 3.0 or 3.1? And i also know that some tablets works on 2.* version. If so, how many tablets was built for 2.* android? I hope i dont miss big audience if i will develop for 3.* API, not to 2.*?

Comment: Depending on what specifics you will use, you could check what is supported in the android compatibility packages to be sure not to miss even 2.x audience. Anyway, you should develop for the latest 3.x release but just take care to be perfectly aware of the differences between minor releases. That conditions your minSdk parameter in AndroidManifest. Don't forget that 4.0 should be released that fall… BUT, if your time to market is critical and very short, check which is the most present 3.x release and constraint your development for that release.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check the differences between Android 2.* and Android 3.* for tablets. After that depending on the results and the specific API's that you need to use you can choose which version of Android to use.

Comment: "Anyway, you should develop for the latest 3.x release" 
hmm, why? if I develop for 3.2, can users with 3.0 run my app?

"Don't forget that 4.0 should be released that fall"
I'm not sure that application built with 4.0 wiil run on 3.* versions..

Comment: If you want your application to run on more devices you have to build it for lower Android version (as much as you can, depending on the specifics you need to develop it).So it depends on you and what you want and need.

Answer (score 0):

Android documentation says that all their SDK releases are forward friendly and that seems to be the case when using an emulator.  I have an application that was written in 2.0, recently upgraded to 2.1 and we have some people in the office that have XOOM tablets (3.0) and we cant get it installed.

After some modifications to the manifest (suggested steps from droid dev portal) it still wont install on the XOOM at all.

If you are targeting tablets then i would start with 3.0.  If there are features in 3.1 that you can't live without then have fun.